# Border doesn't fit image

Tags: html, css

I am trying to add a border to my image but I can't get it to fit. it's bigger than the image. I have spent quite a bit of time trying to figure this out but no luck! Any help would be appreciated! Thanks! My current code is below:

```
<div id="main-border">
<img src="../desktop/atitlan.jpg" width="250px" class="wrap">
<h1><strong>About</strong></h1>
<p>The name "Paris" is derived from its early inhabitants, the Celtic Parisii tribe.Paris is often referred to as "The City of Light" ("La Ville Lumière"),[7] both because of its leading role during the Age of Enlightenment, and more literally because Paris was one of the first European cities to adopt gas street lighting. In the 1860s, the boulevards and streets of Paris were illuminated by fifty-six thousand gas lamps. Since the late 19th century, Paris is also known as Panam in French slang. Inhabitants are known in English as "Parisians" and in French as Parisien, pejoratively also called Parigots</p>

</div>



#main-border {
background : url(../desktop/background.gif);
background-size : 100% 100%;
height: 700px;
width: 650px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
float: left;
margin-top: 20px;
margin-left: 30px;

 }


#main-border p {
margin: 40px;
margin-top: 0;

}

.wrap {
float: left;
padding-top: 30px;
padding-left: 30px;
margin: 20px;
border: 1px solid black;

 }

#main-border h1 {
margin-bottom: 0;
text-indent: 1px;
 }
```

Comment: I don't think you can add border INSIDE the image. Only around it.

Comment: remove padding from .wrap class http://jsfiddle.net/au71saLo/

Comment: @ MightyPork: border-inset is your friend.

Answer (score 2):

You need to remove the padding from the .wrap element.

This is adding the 30px gap on the top and the left.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I create a fiddle for you: http://jsfiddle.net/shannabarnard/meh15n6h/

Replace your CSS with this CSS and the boarder will wrap neatly around the image for you:

```
#main-border {
background : url(../desktop/background.gif);
background-size : 100% 100%;
height: 700px;
width: 650px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
float: left;
margin-top: 0;
margin-left: 0;

 }


#main-border p {
margin: 0;
margin-top: 0;

}

.wrap {
float: left;
padding-top: 0;
padding-left: 0;
margin: 20px;
border: 1px solid black;

 }

#main-border h1 {
margin-bottom: 0;
text-indent: 1px;
 }
```